# Batch - Moving file up a level if it's the only file in the directory

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have several hundred folders. Some of my folders only have one file in them. If a folder contains only one file, I'd like to move the file up a directory, to it's parent file, and then delete the now empty folder. I hope I'm making my question clear. I'm assuming the best way to do this, would be with a batch file? I'm on Windows.

```
- Root Directory
   - Folder 1
      - File 1*
   - Folder 2
      - File 1
      - File 2
   - Folder 3
      - File 1*
   - Folder 4
      - File 1
      - File 2
      - File 3
```

I'd like the files with asterisks to be moved up to the root directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should help you out. A few notes about what it's doing.

- The first for loop walks the directory tree from the current directory
- The second for loop counts just files (no directories), then if there is just one file it is moved to the parent directory
- The 3rd for loop counts both files and subdirectories, and only tries removing if empty

You should find that running this multiple times will move a single file up multiple levels of a directory tree - if it's the only file at each level.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /r /d %%d in (*) do (
    for /f %%f in ('dir /b /a-d "%%d\*" 2^>NUL ^| find /c /v ""') do     set filecount=%%f
    if !filecount! EQU 1 move "%%d\*" "%%~dpd"
    for /f %%f in ('dir /b "%%d\*" 2^>NUL ^| find /c /v ""') do set filecount=%%f 
    if !filecount! EQU 0 rd "%%d"
)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Although it's a bit slow, and it didn't remove the now empty folders, this worked well for me. Thanks again!

Comment: Good to hear. Only folders that are completely empty - no sub folders nor hidden files. Each time you run, single files will shift a directory higher and more empty folders will be removed.